# on Android Browser chrome firefox opera xeditable don't become editable

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'm using xeditable plugin with intraweb with bootstrap for an application I'm developing.
Of Android when I make editable fields with the code `$ ('# myselectore')`. Editable ()
fields become non-editable. After several times we hit him become editable but when I press the button to change the given popup disappears and refreshing the page is run.

What can it be?
On safari firefox and chrome on windows everything works even on safari on ios.
Only on Android I have this problem.

[This is the table on firefox on windows. It works link editable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxGqg.png)
I'm using the library iwboostrap kattunga and third-party components explained in this link [link] https://github.com/kattunga/IWBootstrapFramework/wiki/Third-party-plugins. In particular I'm using the bootstrap-table and xeditable plugin.
Event associated with the load-success.bs.table run grid by the method
IWBSExecuteAsyncJScript education jquery $ ("# DBTABLE"). Editable () without any parameter, to test the right and after loading the links become non-editable.
Use a rest event to populate the grid and after loading is performed load-success.bs.table to make editable links.
The problem occurs only on android ios on safari it all works.
The command `$ ("# DBTABLE")`. Editable () does not make it editable links.
Trying putting another button on the form and click on the event by running `$ ("# DBTABLE")`. Editable () makes them editable but when I edit them to the pop-up disappears and the page undergoes a refresh.

Comment: An example code to reproduce the issue is a must in this type of questions.

Comment: Yes you are in reason I edit the question.

Comment: This is unreadable. Please format better your question and your text.

Comment: I run this method to make the table editable link:(with correct sintax)
IWBSExecuteAsyncJScript ('' $ ('' # MYTABLE "). editable ();");  in the asynchronous event (load-success.bs.table).
What happens is the following thing:
-in Android links become non-editable (in other browser like safari on ios or in windows all works!)
-if I try repeatedly to run:
IWBSExecuteAsyncJScript ('' $ ('' # MYTABLE "). Edit ();"); the links become editable but when I click the link exits the popup to change the value and the keyboard disappears not allowing me to change the value.